# Vim repeat macro recorded under a capital letter

Tags: macos, vim

Normally I record vim macros using `q[some letter]` and replay it using `@[some letter]`

I just saved a macro using `qT` and I'm tryin `@T` to replay it.  But when I do `@T` it just runs `@t` (the lowercase one).

Any idea how I can store and replay macros stored in uppercase letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the vim reference manual, in the section on registers,

> 4. Named registers "a to "z or "A to "Z
>    Vim fills these registers only when you say so.  Specify them as
>    lowercase
>    letters to replace their previous contents or as uppercase letters to
>    append
>    to their previous contents.  When the '>' flag is present in
>    'cpoptions' then
>    a line break is inserted before the appended text.

So recording into the `T` register actually just appends to the `t` register. The lower and upper case registers are not separate.

Comment: Ah... I had looked at macros documentation but somehow missed that it was appending.  Thanks for the answer